# Heroku push issue: Bower resolver not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, npm, bower

Do you know about [Javascript fatigue](https://medium.com/@ericclemmons/javascript-fatigue-48d4011b6fc4#.2xyudmezk)?

Now I do.

I'm not a javascript developer, but i'm using Node and Angular for my side project server.

All my node packages are installed with `npm` and my angular packages are installer with `bower`. Because [that's the way I learned it](https://scotch.io/tag/node-js). I maintain a `package.json` and a `bower.json` to install everything. Usually, what I do is:

```
npm install
bower install
```

but Heroku only install npm package, so the solution was to include a post install script in `package.json`

It worked quite perfectly, unless a couple of libraries which were not maintained anymore (but this is another problem).

Quite perfectly since today, when I'm stuck on the heroku error message:

```
bower angular#*            ENORESOLVER Bower resolver not found: bower-npm-resolver
```

Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name"            : "my-marvelous-app",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.0.0",
    "npm": "3.3.6"
    },
  "main"            : "server.js",
  "dependencies"    : {
        "express"               : "4.5.x",
        "mongoose"              : "4.2.x",
        ...
        [a bunch of important packages...]
        ...
        "vorpal"                : "latest",
        "bower"                 : "1.7.x"
  },
  "scripts"         : {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
  }
}
```

and my `bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-marvelous-backoffice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular"               : "latest",
    "angular-bootstrap"     : "latest",
    "angular-cookies"       : "latest",
    "angular-route"         : "latest",
    "bootstrap"             : "latest",
    "font-awesome"          : "latest"
  }
}
```

I don't know what to do. `npm install` works locally on my machine, but not on heroku. Please do not advise me to use another package manager like `yarn` or whatever, I'm a mobile developer and I don't have much the time to learn another hype stuff wich will be outdated in six monthes. (sorry for the cinisism, it's javascript fatigue!)

**EDIT**

I finally figured out a `.bowerrc` file with this configuration

```
{
    "directory": "public/libs",
    "resolvers": [
        "bower-npm-resolver"
    ]
}
```

I deleted the `resolvers` entry and i works again. I had to delete some `npm` angular packages however...

Answer (score 5):

I hit this as well with a project I inherited. The solution turned out to be:

```
[sudo] npm install -g bower-npm-resolver
```

Although in your case, removing the "resolvers": section from your `.bowerrc` also works, since you have no dependencies in `bower.json` that start with the `npm:` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't `npm -g` something, since i'm on heroku and everything must be in the `package.json`. If i had some `npm:` prefixes,  should I added `bower-npm-resolver` directly in `package.json`?